# Where is the Holy Spirit in Jesus life before baptism in the river Jordan happen?

Tags: life-of-jesus, baptism, pneumatology

Baptism in the Jordan River is where Jesus received the anointing of the Holy Spirit.

> **The Baptism of Jesus**
>   …16As soon as Jesus was baptized, He went up out of the water. Suddenly the heavens were opened, and He saw the Spirit of God descending like a dove and resting on Him. 17And a voice from heaven said, “This is My beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased!”(Matthew3:16-17)

Would it mean that Jesus for thirty years is living without the Holy Spirit dwelling in His soul?

Comment: from which denominations point of view are you asking? Many denominations believe in the trinity but from your questions it seems you believe them to be separate?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from Trinitarian perspective shared by the 3 mainstream branches of Christianity: Roman Catholic, Orthodox, and Protestant.

[This article](https://www.reformation21.org/blogs/why-did-jesus-need-the-holy-sp.php) succinctly shows how Jesus in His human nature needed the Holy Spirit power especially at critical junctures of His mission on earth.  The anointing at the Jordan river's baptism signified God the Father revealing Jesus to be Messiah and the Holy Spirit empowering Jesus in His human nature for the role.  See another [article](https://www.gpcweb.org/the-holy-spirit--6-the-holy-spirit-and-jesus-christ) discussing the relationship of Jesus with the Holy Spirit.

Jesus as human being was conceived by the Holy Spirit, so the human nature Jesus already had the Holy Spirit since birth.  The anointing at baptism didn't imply that the Holy Spirit was not yet given by the Father, but more of **empowerment**, probably similar to how we as believers can, sometime after baptism, be given [spiritual gifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_gift) for ministering to the body of Christ.  Jesus did not sin before baptism, so technically He didn't need to be baptized.  The baptism was the occasion chosen by God the Father for the unveiling.

About your comment:

> Your link cited Jesus said "the Spirit of the Lord is now upon me". Does it mean before baptism the Holy Spirit was not yet present?

the context was Jesus preaching at the synagogue in his hometown, Nazareth: [Luke 4:14-30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+4%3A14-30&version=NLT).  This was **after** his baptism / annointing.  Jesus was **announcing** the fulfillment of [Isaiah 61:1-2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isa+61%3A1-2&version=NLT).  He was referring to the empowerment mentioned above.  It is safe to assume that throughout the many villages and cities he visited before his crucifixion, he made similar announcement because people needed to know the good news of the coming Kingdom of God and Jesus taught them how to respond (i.e. by repenting, believing, and then living according to the ethics of the Kingdom).

Comment: Your link cited Jesus said "the Spirit of the Lord is now upon me". Does it mean before baptism the Holy Spirit was not yet present?

Comment: @FrancisSophia I edited the answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting mentioning something doesn't mean it didn't happen. For example every meal wasn't recorded, but we know Jesus still ate. There are occasions when meals/food are mentioned:

- Last Supper (Luke 22)
- Feed 5000 (Matt 14)
- Eating Fish and honey (Luke 24)

These denote special occasions, just like baptism is a special occasion so mentioning the Holy Spirit doesn't mean there was no Spirit earlier.